# I'm attempting to use Dispatcher in my WPF application but I don't seem to be able to get access to System.Windows.Threading

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to make a simple game using WPF and C#. Started on a loop for the combat and after reading this and that decided I needed to use Dispatcher to update the UI. When I try to use when I try to add using System.Windows.Threading; I get an error stating that "The type or namespace name does not exist in System.Windows." Looked up that issue and read that I needed to add WindowsBase.dll as a reference. I am using visual studio 2022 when I try to add it as a reference don't see it in the list of COM references. How do I use the System.Windows.Threading namespace? Do I even need it or should I be using something else?

Comment: Please show a csproj content. Are you using .NET6/7/8 or .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: Can you show the code that is giving you this error?

Comment: How did you create the project? Best to create a WPF project using the Visual Studio wizard, it will add the references you need.

Comment: @Lukasz Szczygielik I believe I am using NET6 but I'm not sure as I started the project over a year ago and have been working on it very slowly in my free time. I have found the .csoroj.user file but I am unsure as to how to open it to provide the contents.

Comment: @KlausGütter  How much of the code would you like to see? Do you want the entire class  or just the function I am trying to add the Dispatcher to.

Comment: @BenJohnson `csproj` has info about the framework version, that's why I asked about it.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek I think I have it. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Update="App.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Update="MainWindow.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Comment: Just form your questions I take it that Dispatcher is not available in net Core. From what I am seeing I should be using SynchronizationContext instead. I will look into how to use this. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: How do I mark this question as answered?